$ x_1x_2\ldots x_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n} \left(e_1x_1+\ldots+e_nx_n\right)^n $
today I try to prove that this
$$
x_1x_2\ldots x_n=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n}
\left(e_1x_1+\ldots+e_nx_n\right)^n
$$
here my prove
$$
\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n}
\left(e_1x_1+\ldots+e_nx_n\right)^n=
$$
$$
\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n}
\sum_{\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n=n}
\binom{n}{\alpha_1\ \alpha_2\ \ldots\ \alpha_n}
{e_1}^{\alpha_1} {e_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {e_n}^{\alpha_n}
{x_1}^{\alpha_1} {x_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {x_n}^{\alpha_n}=
$$
$$
\sum_{\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n=n}
\binom{n}{\alpha_1\ \alpha_2\ \ldots\ \alpha_n}
{x_1}^{\alpha_1} {x_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {x_n}^{\alpha_n}
\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n}
{e_1}^{\alpha_1} {e_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {e_n}^{\alpha_n}
$$
$$
\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n}
{e_1}^{\alpha_1} {e_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {e_n}^{\alpha_n}=1
$$
becuase ${e_1}^{\alpha_1} {e_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {e_n}^{\alpha_n}=0$ when $e_i=0$ for some $i\Rightarrow$
$$
\sum_{e_i\in\{0,1\}}(-1)^{n-e_1-e_2-\ldots-e_n}
\left(e_1x_1+\ldots+e_nx_n\right)^n=
\sum_{\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n=n}
\binom{n}{\alpha_1\ \alpha_2\ \ldots\ \alpha_n}
{x_1}^{\alpha_1} {x_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots {x_n}^{\alpha_n}=\left(x_1+\ldots+x_n\right)^n
$$
Here I can't find where I missed the error.

The mistake is in the step where you said the product $e_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots e_n^{\alpha_n} = 0$ when one of the $e_i$’s is $0$. That’s not true when $\alpha_i=0$ because $0^0=1\ne 0$.

There’s a much simpler way to prove this. Let $p(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be the polynomial on the RHS.

Since every term in the sum has degree at most $n$, $p$ also has degree at most $n$.
Substitute $x_1=0$. Then $e_1$ appears only in the exponent, so the sum over $e_1$ gives zero. In other words, $x_1$ is a factor of $p$.
By the same argument, $x_i$ is a factor of $p$ for all $i$.

Therefore, $p$ must be of the form $c x_1 \cdots x_n$ for some constant $c$. Substituting $x_1=\cdots=x_n=1$ gives
\begin{align}
c&= p(1,\ldots,1)
\\
&= \frac1{n!} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} k^n \binom{n}{k}
\\
&= \frac1{n!} \frac{d^n}{dt^n}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} e^{kt} \Bigg|_{t=0}
\\
&= \frac1{n!} \frac{d^n}{dt^n}(e^t-1)^n\Bigg|_{t=0}
\\
&= 1.
\end{align}

Nice, thank you very much. A much simpler solution than mine.
